# File format changes from MPEG to .DVD

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, blender-internal-render-engine

I have an issue with rendering an animation. I set the file format to mpeg but when it finishes rendering the output file that it gives me is '.dvd'. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Open up the *Encoding* panel and choose *h264* from the *Presets* dropdown in order to encode it as mpg file.

Comment: on the rendered file just change the extension from .DVD to .mpg

Comment: @poor that will render an mpeg 4 (part 10) file... but what to do if the desired output is mpeg2 ?

Comment: @cegaton Oops misread the question... You are right MPEG-2 always results in `.dvd` - renaming also works here.

Comment: I prefer to use Xvid under output and Xvid also under encoding that works better for me

Answer (score 1):

Here some steps that you can follow:

1. Set the video format to *FFMPEG*
2. Go in the *Encoding* drop-down just below the color settings in the bottom-left corner of the drop-down
3. In the *Video* drop-down, in the *Video Codec* settings, choose the *H.264* settings
   ( I think your problem is that there might be a default setting in Blender)
4. Just to be safe Double-Check the Steps.
5. Check [if there is any bug](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1377), or consult a [video tutorial on how to report one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTD0OJq_rF4)

Answer (score -2):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but this is more for anybody else that has this problem and stumbles upon this in the future. I am also new to blender and tried to render as an .mpeg file. I also got the .dvd file problem. Here's what I did (there may be better ways, but this is just what I came up with on the spot(it worked)). I'm using a Windows 10 computer.

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CC1rLDwHaY0
   (shows how to change file type, pretty sure there are tutorials for any other OS you might have to do this) If this works, skip to: step 5.
2. If changing to mp4 doesn't work, load the original file into Movie Maker.
3. Add any audio you may have had when rendering.
4. Then follow this vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QWbiTtaK_E (now it should show up as an mp4 file)
5. Now use this converter and it should be done: http://www.convertfiles.com/convert/video/MP4-to-MPEG.html

I know it's not fun, but this is how I did it for a small competition project. Hope it helps.

Comment: Howdy Anonymous.  Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers  Can you please make your answer here complete?